# Optimize mysql query for better performance

Tags: mysql, performance

My sql query:

```
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(SUBSTR(p2.post_date,1,4), p2.post_title, p2.post_name) AS thumb, p.ID, p.post_name, p.post_title, p.post_content 
    FROM 
        wp_posts p 
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m 
                 ON p.ID = m.post_id 
                 AND m.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
                 AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
        LEFT JOIN wp_posts p2 
                 ON m.meta_value = p2.ID 
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
                 ON p.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id 
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
                 ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
                 ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post' 
        AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' 
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id 
        AND wp_terms.name = 'my_cat' 
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0,50
```

Performance is bad, it takes long time to get result. Please help me optimizing for better performance. Thanks!

UPDATE:

- I want to get posts from a category of a wordpress site.
- I get these posts from normal site (not wordpress) which can access to that wordpress site's database
- The Wordpress site has some tables as above query: wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms (as standard wordpress site db)
- Is there a more simple way to get wordpress post from database?

UPDATE #2

Thank you all. I founded my own solution. I can get the post from wordpress database by using built-in wpdb class. Post here for anybody need it:

```
        include_once('path-to-wp-site/wp-load.php');
        global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT ID, post_date, post_title, post_name, post_content,
              CONCAT('http://your-wp-site.com/wp-content/uploads/',pm2.meta_value) AS post_image
        FROM $wpdb->posts p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
              AND tt.term_id IN (63)
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm2 ON pm.meta_value = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
        WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
              AND p.post_type = 'post'
              AND p.post_date BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ORDER BY p.post_date DESC"

        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
        var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Adding `index` which are covered under `ON` and `WHERE` will help you to optimize it. Use `explain` to get which indexes are getting used. Can you please `explain` output for above query?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Try to use `JOIN` (INNER JOIN) instead of `LEFT JOIN` if you can

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.